# INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_MANIFEST_MALFORMED caused by <provider>

Tags: android, android-manifest

So, I got this problem out of the blue. It was all fine the day before but suddenly when I tried to run my app from Android Studio it failed saying `INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_MANIFEST_MALFORMED`.

I checked LogCat and found this entry

> 12-11 14:34:44.904 28710-28747/? W/PackageParser: /data/local/tmp/com.myapp (at Binary XML file line #148): `<provider>` does not include authorities attribute
>
> 12-11 14:34:45.084 2619-2756/? W/PackageParser: /data/app/vmdl-1571002842.tmp (at Binary XML file line #148): `<provider>` does not include authorities attribute

So, I went to Android Manifest and I found the authorities attribute for the provider still there, nothing missing. Here is my `AndroidManifest.xml`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest
    package="com.myapp"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"> 

    <permission
        android:name="com.myapp.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature"/>

    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true"/>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SYNC_STATS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.myapp.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SYNC_SETTINGS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SYNC_SETTINGS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.AUTHENTICATE_ACCOUNTS"/>

    <application
        android:name=".SisiApplication"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".SplashActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:noHistory="true"
            android:theme="@style/AppThemeNoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".LoginActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_login"
            android:noHistory="true"
            android:theme="@style/AppThemeNoActionBar"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize|stateVisible"/>
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_main"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>
        <activity
            android:name=".SurveyActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_survey"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"/>
        <activity
            android:name=".StoreActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_add_store"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"/>
        <activity
            android:name=".OrderActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_order"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"/>
        <activity
            android:name=".StoreDetailActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_store_detail"
            android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value=".MainActivity"/>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".OrderDetailActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_order_detail"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>
        <activity
            android:name=".SurveyDetailActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_survey_detail"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>
        <activity
            android:name=".MapActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_map"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>

        <provider
            android:name=".data.providers.CRMContentProvider"
            android:authorities="com.myapp.providers"
            android:exported="false"
            android:syncable="true"/>

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version"/>
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="xxx"/>

        <service
            android:name=".services.AuthenticatorService"
            android:enabled="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.accounts.AccountAuthenticator"/>
            </intent-filter>

            <meta-data
                android:name="android.accounts.AccountAuthenticator"
                android:resource="@xml/authenticator"/>
        </service>
        <service
            android:name=".services.SyncService"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true"
            android:process=":sync">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.content.SyncAdapter"/>
            </intent-filter>
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.content.SyncAdapter"
                android:resource="@xml/syncadapter"/>
        </service>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

I even made sure I used the same authorities in the code

```
public class CRMContentProvider extends ContentProvider {

    public static final String AUTHORITY = "com.myapp.providers";
    ...
}
```

What did I do wrong? Please help!

**UPDATE**

So, the problem was here

```
<provider
    android:name="net.grandcentrix.tray.provider.TrayProvider"
    android:authorities="@string/tray__authority"
    android:exported="false"
    android:multiprocess="false" />
```

It was added by [Tray library](https://github.com/grandcentrix/tray). But I still don't know why it suddenly caused error.

Comment: The errors refers to line #148 of the manifest. The manifest you posted does not have that many lines. Assuming you're using the gradle plugin for builds, have a look at `.../build/intermediates/manifests/full/.../AndroidManifest.xml` for the manifest file after manifest merging. The problematic `provider` might be merged from some other component's manifest.

Comment: You're right @laalto, I got a new lead now. The problem is `android:authorities="@string/tray__authority"`. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could finally solve the problem, although I still don't know why it happened in the first place. Here's what I did.

I put a string resource,

```
<string name="tray__authority" translatable="false">com.myapp.tray</string>
```

And then, I replace the `<provider>` in manifest like so,

```
<provider
    android:name="net.grandcentrix.tray.provider.TrayProvider"
    android:authorities="@string/tray__authority"
    android:exported="false"
    android:multiprocess="false"
    tools:replace="android:authorities"/>
```

This way, it will replace the provider generated by Tray. It seems weird but it didn't work when I didn't replace the `<provider>`.

Comment: I solved that by replacing authorities value with actual value, not string resource. Problem started for me after adding more translation files values.xml to different directories for other languages..

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should refer to an Android string resource for your authority.

Try this:

```
<provider
  android:name=".data.providers.CRMContentProvider"
  android:authorities="@string/my_provider_authority"
  android:exported="false"
  android:syncable="true"/>
```

Comment: But those meta data are for GMaps API, not for the provider. Why inside the provider?

Comment: I don't think it will work either, see https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=40455

Comment: OK, I tried your answer, but to no avail. Same error.

Comment: Even after a clean build? Can you try the full name of the provider class? `android.name="com.myapp.data.providers.CRMContentProvider"`.